Retrieving a Firebase Node Key from Database - iOS, Swift
I'm trying to set up chat functionality for an app I'm currently building using Firebase as BaaS, where users on the app can send chat messages to one another.
From reading the Firebase documentation and answers from other questions on the topic, my understanding that a common and effective way to set up my NoSQL data schema to achieve this end is as follows: 
{App_Root_Node:

    Users: {
        "UID_Adam": {
          "myName" : "Adam",
          "myAge" : "24",
          ...
          "myChatThreads": {
             "ChatThreadID1" : True,
             "ChatThreadID2" : True,
             ...
             "ChatThreadID5" : True,
             }
          }
       "UID_Amy": {
          "myName" : "Amy",
          "myAge" : "23",
          ...
          "myChatThreads": {
             "ChatThreadID1" : True,
             ...
             }
          }

   ChatThreads: {
       "chatThreadID1" : {
              "MessageID1" : {
                 "senderUID" : "",
                 "messageBody" : "",
                 "messageTimeStamp" : "",
               }
              "Message ID2: {...},
               ...
       "chatThreadID2" : {
                   ...
               },
       ...
       "chatThreadID5" : {
                   ...
               }
       }

Consider a case where Adam is sending Amy a message that says, "Hello, Amy!". If the above schema is a good way to go about the task, my understanding is that I need to implement the following relationships in the data:

Create a new chatThreadID (i.e. Adam's newly initiated chatThreadID) once a user begins a conversation, and write a copy of this key at 3 distinct locations in the database: 

a. ~Root/ChatThreads/, the node which holds information about all active chat threads on the app 
b. ~Root/Users/UID_Adam/myChatThreads, the sender's, i.e. Adam's, active chat threads node, which lists all chat threads that Adam is part of
c. ~Root/Users/UID_Amy/myChatThreads, the receiver's, i.e. Amy's, active chat threads node, which lists all chat threads that Amy is part of 

Create a new messageID for Adam's, "Hello, Amy!" message, and write this messageID to a single location under: ~Root/ChatThreads/. This messageID is a key pointing to Adam's message data

Amy's device will be able to read Adam's message through the means of an observer placed at (c) ~Root/Users/UID_Amy/myChatThreads, which observes newly created chatThreadID keys. Amy's device will read message data stored under ~Root/ChatThreads/ using these keys. 
I'm having trouble writing a copy of the chatThreadID simultaneously to  (a), (b), and (c) locations listed above, while creating a messageID key to store under ~Root/ChatThreads/. I'm using the following code (iOS, Swift) to achieve this:   
func sendMessage(messageData: [String : String]) {

let adamUID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
let amyUID = recipientUser["UID"]!

let ref = Database.database().reference()

let chatThreadKey = ref.child("ChatThreads").childByAutoId().key
let childUpdates = [
    "/ChatThreads/\(chatThreadKey)": messageData, *[NEED HELP HERE]
    "/Users/\(adamUID)/\(chatThreadKey)/": messageData,
    "/Users/\(amyUID)/myChatThreads\(chatThreadKey)/": messageData,
    ]
ref.updateChildValues(childUpdates)

}
The above lines of code allow me to successfully write a copy of the chatThreadID to each of the three database locations listed above. However, in order to write a newly created messageID under the "/ChatThreads/(chatThreadKey)" path, as in (2), I need to know what the chatThreadID key is. How do I retrieve the chatThreadID key for the new chat thread that Adam just created? 
I've considered retrieving a data snapshot of the newly created chatThreadID, and getting this chatThreadID's key using the "path.key()" Firebase method to create a new messageID at the "/ChatThreads/(chatThreadKey)" path. However, how do I make sure that if another user, John, just created a new chatThreadID, that the observer will not retrieve a data snapshot for John's chatThreadID instead?

Is there a reason you're writing the messages to multiple locations? Why don't you just create the messages under /ChatThreads/chatThreadID/messages and observe them from there?

@ChrisEdginton As per my understanding, it is necessary for each user to have a copy of chatThreadID keys in their user folder in order to be able to observe for the relevant chatThreads in /ChatThreads/chatThreadID/messageID/messages, using the key as a reference. It's proving challenging in code to retroactively get the chatThreadID once it's created and then create a new messageID under that exact same node. Perhaps I'm going about it the wrong way?
(I know the code shows that I'm trying to copy message data to three different locations. However, that is not the case.)
